# SQL - group by with two colums agregation problem

Tags: c#, .net, sql, oracle

My today's problem is that I have a table that has rows like that:

```
ID NAME NUMBER IDN
1  dsad 500600 12
1  dsad 600700 13
2  kkkk 111222 56
2  kkkk 333232 57
```

in one ID example 1 i have 2 identical names 2 different numbers and different IDN.

What i want is to extract single row For each Id where the idn value is the smaller one.
So I want to have sommething like that

```
1  dsad  500600 12
2  kkkk  111222 56
```

Is it posible to write a single sql to have that result? I tried to group that by ID and NAME and have the min(IDN) but I'm stuck with the number field :) any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were almost there, just add the `MIN(Number)` field.

```
SELECT  ID
        , NAME
        , MIN(NUMBER)
        , MIN(IDN)
FROM    ATable
GROUP BY
        ID
        , NAME
```

**In response to comment**

Following would get you the records with the `MIN(IDN)`, regardless what the number for that specific record is.

```
SELECT  t.*
FROM    ATable t
        INNER JOIN (        
          SELECT  ID, IDN = MIN(IDN)
          FROM    ATable
          GROUP BY ID
        ) tmin ON tmin.ID = t.ID
                  AND tmin.IDN = t.IDN
```

Comment: I really can't do that because I don't wan't the MIN value from NUMBER, I wan't the value that's in the row where MIN(IDN) Is

Comment: @shin - An unfortunate coïncidence but in your example it matched, I misinterpreted it. I have added a query that takes care of it.

Comment: Ye It worked :D  It took me a while coz my ATable was already a big select whith joins :D Thanks m8 ;D

Comment: @cyberkiwi, true but I think we can assume IDN to be unique. If it is not, adding DISTINCT would suffice.

Comment: it won't suffice. the outer query will show >1 record for the same IDN without another level of query

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @TABLE table (ID int, [NAME] varchar(100),NUMBER int ,IDN int)
insert into @TABLE SELECT 1,'dsad',500600,12
insert into @TABLE SELECT 1,'dsad',600700, 13
insert into @TABLE SELECT 2,'kkkk',111222, 56
insert into @TABLE SELECT 2,'kkkk',333232, 57

select t.ID, t.[Name], t.Number, t.IDN
from (
   select [NAME],min(IDN) as minIDN
   from @TABLE group by [NAME]
) as x inner join @TABLE as t on t.[Name]=x.[Name] and t.IDN = x.minIDN;
```

Comment: +1 but this is SQL Server syntax. I don't think the testscript as it is is portable to Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

Version that only uses a left join and no subqueries, with SQlite3 and a shell script since I don't have anything other at hand ATM:

```
#!/bin/sh

rm -f test.sqlite
sqlite3 test.sqlite << AAA
CREATE TABLE test (id int, name text, number int, idn int);
INSERT INTO test VALUES(1,'dsad',500600,12);
INSERT INTO test VALUES(1,'dsad',600700,13);
INSERT INTO test VALUES(2,'kkkk',111222,56);
INSERT INTO test VALUES(2,'kkkk',333232,57);
INSERT INTO test VALUES(1,'dsad',600700,9);
INSERT INTO test VALUES(2,'kkkk',333232,59);
INSERT INTO test VALUES(2,'cccc',333232,59);
SELECT a.* FROM test a
    LEFT JOIN test b ON
            a.id=b.id AND
            a.name=b.name
            AND a.idn > b.idn
            WHERE b.id IS NULL;
AAA
# Result:
# 1|dsad|600700|9
# 2|cccc|333232|59
# 2|kkkk|111222|56
```

Can anyone comment on where the performance is better? I think that matters, too!

Comment: Without indexes and on this small set of data, your solution is twice as fast as mine. Adding an index on ID makes both solutions equally fast. Using 60 records, the solution I gave (with index) is six times as fast as this. *Note that I'm using SQL Server io Oracle. Oracle's milleage may vary.* +1 nevertheless.